# Python SSH connected as a sudoer

Tags: python, ssh, sudo, paramiko, sudoers

I need to make a script in python that connects me with my login/pw as a sudoer.

Here is my script.

```
import paramiko
import sys

host = '1.0.0.0'
port = 22
username = 'login'
password = 'pw'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=host, port=port, username=username, password=password)


chan = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
chan.get_pty()
chan.exec_command('sudo su -l axis_0;mkdir olivier')
print(chan.recv(1024))
```

But the folder olivier is never created..

Comment: You seem to expect `sudo; mkdir` to execute `mkdir` under `sudo` but that's not what it does. It runs `sudo`, then when that finishes, it runs `mkdir` running under your regular account.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my command to this one, and it works.

```
chan.exec_command('sudo -iu axis_0 sh -c "cd FOLDER;"')
```